# Trying to understand behavior of `test <command>` in Bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have this simple C program (test.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     exit (1);
}
```

Obviously, the exit code of this program is 1:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
1
```

But when I run `test ./a.out`, the result of the test doesn't match the exit code:

```
$ test ./a.out
$ echo $?
0
```

So what is actually being tested? Why is the result of the test 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test` is a Bash built-in, often invoked by the alternative name `[`.

The last command (`test ./a.out`) exits with status 0 indicating success because `test ./a.out` checks whether `./a.out` as a string has one or more characters in it (is not an empty string), and because it isn't an empty string, returns success or 0.  The `test ./a.out` command line does not execute your `a.out` program — as you could see by printing something from within your program.

As written, your program doesn't need the `<stdio.h>` header or the arguments to `main()` — it should be `int main(void)`.  You could lose `<stdlib.h>` too if you use `return 1;` instead of `exit(1);`:

```
int main(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

To use the exit status in an `if` condition in the shell, just use it directly:

```
if ./a.out ; then
    echo Success
else
    echo Failure
fi
```

**Rule of Thumb:** Don't call C programs `test` because you will be confused sooner or later — usually sooner rather than later.

Comment: I name all my little test programs `testxxx` where `xxx` describes what it's testing.

Comment: @Barmar: But you don't use an empty string in place of `xxx`, which is what my rule of thumb advises against.  And with source code `test.c`, it's tempting to type `make test` but then you run into trouble.

Comment: Right, I was agreeing with you, and mentioning what I do.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your C program returns "1" to the shell (I'd prefer"return()" over exit()", but...)
2. If you wanted to actually run "a.out" in conjunction with the "*nix" test command, you'd use syntax like:

   ```
   `./a.out` # classic *nix
   ```

   or

   ```
   $(./a.out) # Bash
   ```
3. If you did that, however, "test" would read the value printed to "stdout", and *NOT* the value returned by your program on exit.
4. You can read more about `test` here:

   - [test(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)
   - [The classic test command: Bash hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)
   - [Understanding exit codes and how to use them in Bash scripts](http://bencane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-bash-scripts/)
5. Here is an example:

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("%d\n", argc);
  return 2;
}
```

Shell script:

```
echo "Assign RETVAL the return value of a.out:"
./a.out RETVAL=$? echo " " RETVAL=$RETVAL

echo "Assign RETVAL the value printed to stdout by a.out:"
RETVAL=$(./a.out) echo " " RETVAL=$RETVAL

echo "Turn an 'trace' and run a.out with 'test':" 
set -x 
if [ $(./a.out) -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "One" 
else
  echo "Not One"
fi
```

Example output:

```
paulsm@vps2:~$ ./tmp.sh
Assign RETVAL the return value of a.out:
1
  RETVAL=2
Assign RETVAL the value printed to stdout by a.out:
  RETVAL=1
Turn an 'trace' and run a.out with 'test':
+++ ./a.out
++ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
++ echo One
One
```

ALSO:

A couple of points that have already been mentioned:

a. `return 1` is generally a better choice than `exit (1)`.

b. "test" is probably a poor name for your executable - because it collides with the built-in "test" command.  Something like "test_return" might be a better choice.